# How do I resolve dependency issues in bundler?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I want to use the latest version of the oauth2 gem, I add it to my gemfile and run bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    oauth2 (= 0.7.0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.3) ruby

    uglifier (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.0.4)
```

Oh ok, well I'll update uglifier with `bundle update uglifier`

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    faraday (0.5.7)

  In Gemfile:
    oauth2 (= 0.7.0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.8) ruby
```

Hmm, so I'll try `bundle update oauth2`?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    oauth2 (= 0.7.0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.3) ruby

    uglifier (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.0.4)
```

Oh that's right.. This is what I was trying to do in the first place. Well, maybe I can specify the newest version of uglifier `gem 'uglifier', "~> 1.2.4"` and `bundle update uglifier` again.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    oauth2 (~> 0.7.0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.8) ruby

    instagram (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.5.7)
```

Well, `bundle update instagram` it is. Nope - back to multi_json incompatibilities between instagram and oauth2.

How do you go about resolving such an issue? Is this just a matter of the Instagram gem needing to be updated to use a newer multi json version? Or is there something else I should be attempting?

Comment: Did you try updating them all at once? `bundle update uglifier multi_json instagram faraday`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and received the same instagram/oauth multi_json version incompatibility

Comment: try updating _everything_ at once with plain old `bundle update`?  Even if you don't want to actually doing that (you've got your Gemfile.lock in source control so you can easily go back to your committed one, right?), it might give you clues about what's going on. Either `bundle update` will fail too and the failure message will be educational, or if it succeeds you can look in the Gemfile.lock and see what versions of what it ended up with.

Comment: @NathanManousos Can you accept my answer if it solves your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Clear out your GEM directories at once and then execute a fresh bundle command. Think this like resetting a computer.

$GEM_PATH is where your gems live (each path is separated with two dots)

bundle show gem_name (will also show you where your gems are)